# In GNU Screen, how to tell how many "multi display mode" connections you have?

Tags: gnu-screen

`screen -ls` does not seem to indicate how many connections I have using `screen -x` (multi display mode).

Example:

```bsh
screen     # create first screen
screen -ls
screen -x  # attach to first screen from a different location
screen -ls
```

Both `screen -ls` commands show the exact same info. There's no indication that there is now 2 attachments to the same screen. Is there a way to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen -ls` will not list it, but you can find out the number of attached screens by looking at the pts devices created for the master process.

The script below will add a number to the end of `screen -ls` with the number of attached screens:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -ls | while read scr
do
    if [[ "$scr" =~ ^[0-9]+\. ]]; then
        pid=${scr%%.*}
        cnt=$(ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/ | grep pts | wc -l)
        echo "$scr [$cnt]"
    else
        echo "$scr"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you, it worked perfectly! The key to this is `ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/ | grep pts`, where `$pid` is the `pid` for `screen` if you want to see how it works.